# Want To Maximized web page to some trigger event?

Tags: javascript, html

There's timer and i setup the time interval to 10000 miliseconds. If i put my web page to minimized mode after 10000 miliseconds i want the page in maximized. if page is maximized mode nothing

how it woyuld be done??

Comment: normal browser page. Or think it would done with web application.

Comment: I really really really really .... really.. hope what you are asking for is not possible... It would be a major annoyance and possibly a security hole...

Answer (score 0):

You can [resize the browser window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.resizeTo) in some browsers, but you can't maximize or minimize a window.